# SignedXml.CheckSIgnature NullReferenceException after updating System.Security.Cryptography.Xml from 4.7.0 to 5.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

After updating `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` from 4.7.0 to 5.0.0 or 6.0.0, with no other changes to my code, I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` in `IsKeyTheCorrectAlgorithm`.  The certificates being used are SHA1 and SHA256 self-signed certificates, created using CNG, CAPI, and OpenSSL.

Comment: I was also getting  a NullReferenceException in CreateDeformatter, my solution was https://stackoverflow.com/a/76182849/584527

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: @ShotikoAkhlouri, yes, see the answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After weeks of searching, I finally found this obscure GitHub issue indicating the solution (but without acknowledging a problem or fixing the issue): https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55383.

The solution is to remove calls to `CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm`, which is apparently no longer needed.

Comment: Issue still applies when updating to dotnet 6.

Comment: GOAT answer, would not have figured this out otherwise