# SignedXML CheckSignature function is not working for validating the SAML response

Tags: c#, .net, azure, saml

I am trying to implement the SAML SSO authentication functionality. In that, while calling the `signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate, true)` function it gives the below error and I am not able to find out what is the rason behind this

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Security.Cryptography.Xml
  StackTrace:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.IsKeyTheCorrectAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithm key, Type expectedType)
```

Can someone help me with this? It would be a great help.

I have tried removing AddAlgorithm() function while initializing. I want the samlResponse to be valid.

I am using below code to implement SAML authentication:

https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar exception from SignedXml.CheckSignature method:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.RSAPKCS1SignatureDescription.CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm )
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm )
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm )
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(X509Certificate2 , Boolean )
```

When I checked the System.Security.Cryptography source I saw this warning in SignatureDescription class CreateDeformatter method:

```
"CreateDeformatter is not trim compatible because the algorithm implementation referenced by DeformatterAlgorithm might be removed."
```

In my Dockerfile I was setting PublishTrimmed=true.

After removing it, the problem is resolved.