# SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied

Tags: .net, saml, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-7.0

I am using following code as part of SAML authentication, CheckSignature() method is working fine in .net core 3.1 version, however it's not working .Net core 7,  we are getting object reference not set to an instace, what could be the issue, is there any know bug in .Net core 7 ?

public bool IsValid()
{
XmlNodeList nodeList = _xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ds:Signature", _xmlNameSpaceManager);

```
        var signedXml = new SignedXml(_xmlDoc);

        if (nodeList.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);
        return ValidateSignatureReference(signedXml) && **signedXml.CheckSignature(_certificate.Cert, true)** && !IsExpired();
    }
```

Have tried with multipe security certificates, but getting the same issue, if we revert back to .Net 3.1 it's working fine.

Comment: Found the answer here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397688/signedxml-checksignature-nullreferenceexception-after-updating-system-security-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SignedXml.CheckSIgnature NullReferenceException after updating System.Security.Cryptography.Xml from 4.7.0 to 5.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397688/signedxml-checksignature-nullreferenceexception-after-updating-system-security-c)